# Stored procedure how to cater NULL condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am reading a text file as an input to execute the logic in my stored procedure following is the sample of my textfile

```
<tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone>
   <ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID>-1</ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID>
   <ManagementZoneID>0</ManagementZoneID>
   <TSSubZoneNumber>BR101_Moderate/Good_Medium_1</TSSubZoneNumber>
   <TSSubZoneArea>0</TSSubZoneArea>
   <AdjacentRemnantVegArea>23</AdjacentRemnantVegArea>
   <PatchArea>0</PatchArea>
   <CreatedBySystemUser>BBCC Training 1</CreatedBySystemUser>
   <UpdatedBySystemUser>BBCC Training 1</UpdatedBySystemUser>
   <SaveType>1</SaveType>
   <VegetationZoneID>-1</VegetationZoneID>
   <ManagementZoneName />
</tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone>
```

If you noticed `<ManagementZoneName />` don't have any value. In my stored procedure I tried to find if `Managementzone` has value or not but not sure is the right way to do

```
IF @ManagementZoneIDInXML > 0 and @@ManagementZoneIDInXML <> NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone
                  (ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID,
                    ManagementZoneID,
                    VegetationZoneID,
                    TSSubZoneNumber,
                    TSSubZoneArea,
                    AdjacentRemnantVegArea,
                    PatchArea,
                    DateCreated,
                    CreatedBySystemUser,
                    DateUpdated,
                    UpdatedBySystemUser,
                    SaveType,
                    RowTimestamp)
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/NewDataSet/tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone', 2)
    WITH (ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID INT,
          ManagementZoneID INT,
          VegetationZoneID INT,
          TSSubZoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
          TSSubZoneArea NUMERIC(9,2),
          AdjacentRemnantVegArea NUMERIC(9,2),
          PatchArea NUMERIC(9,2),
          DateCreated VARCHAR(50),
          CreatedBySystemUser VARCHAR(50),
          DateUpdated VARCHAR(50),
          UpdatedBySystemUser VARCHAR(50),
          SaveType INT,
          RowTimestamp VARCHAR(50)) XMLDATA
    WHERE 
        ManagementZoneID = @ManagementZoneIDInXML           --Only select the rows that belong to the supplied ManagementZoneID
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone
                  ( ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID ,
                    ManagementZoneID    ,
                    VegetationZoneID    ,
                    TSSubZoneNumber         ,
                    TSSubZoneArea           ,
                    AdjacentRemnantVegArea  ,
                    PatchArea               ,
                    DateCreated             ,
                    CreatedBySystemUser     ,
                    DateUpdated             ,
                    UpdatedBySystemUser     ,
                    SaveType        ,
                    RowTimestamp            )
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/NewDataSet/tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone', 2)
    WITH            (   ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID INT         ,
                    ManagementZoneID    INT         ,
                    VegetationZoneID    INT     ,
                    TSSubZoneNumber         VARCHAR(50)     ,
                    TSSubZoneArea           NUMERIC(9,2)    ,
                    AdjacentRemnantVegArea  NUMERIC(9,2)    ,
                    PatchArea               NUMERIC(9,2)    ,
                    DateCreated             VARCHAR(50)     ,
                    CreatedBySystemUser     VARCHAR(50)     ,
                    DateUpdated             VARCHAR(50)     ,
                    UpdatedBySystemUser     VARCHAR(50) ,
                    SaveType        INT     ,
                    RowTimestamp            VARCHAR(50)     ) XMLDATA
    WHERE VegetationZoneID = @VegetationZoneIDInXML      --Only select the rows that belong to the supplied VegetationZoneID 
                                                         --And no Management zone assigned
END
```

Comment: Use the **isnull()** or **coalesce()** functions, as appropriate for your RDBMS.

Comment: Istead of using `@ManagementZoneIDInXML <> NULL` USE `@ManagementZoneIDInXML IS NOT NULL`

Comment: i just changed like                                                                      " IF ManagementZoneIDInXML > 0 and ManagementZoneIDInXML IS NOT NULL"